# Child Data in Ionic side multi-level menu not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

as per attached picture, my data is not shown properly. How do i remove the "[{"title":..." Leaving just the "Stationery" in my side menu child data? When i clicked my parent item, it will drop down a child value. But instead of showing 'Stationery', it shows '[
        { title: 'Stationery' },
        { title: 'Paper & Pads' },
        { title: 'Technology' },
        { title: 'Ink & Toner' },...'

My menu.html as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="toggleGroup(items)" ng-controller="dropDownCtrl">
 <ion-item>
{{item.title}}
<i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(items) ? 'ion-arrow-up-b' : 'ion-arrow-down-b'"> </i>
</ion-item>
<ion-item ng-show="isGroupShown(items)" menu-close href="#/app/home">
{{item.children}}
</ion-item>
</div>
```

and my controllers.js:

```
starter.controller('dropDownCtrl', function( $scope ) {

$scope.items = [
{title: 'Products',
children: [
    { title: 'Stationery' },
    { title: 'Paper & Pads' },
    { title: 'Technology' },
    { title: 'Ink & Toner' },
    { title: 'Pantry' ,
    children: [
        { title: 'Snacks, Beverages & Condiments' },
        { title: 'Tableware and Pantry Accessories' },
        { title: 'Cleaning Supplies' },
        { title: 'Medical Products' , 
        children: [
            { title: 'First Aids ' },
        ]}
    ]}
]
},
{title: 'My Catalogs'},
{title: 'My RFQs'},
{title: 'My Orders'}
    ];
```

Comment: children is a array not a value .. need to generate your menu alternately .  you need recursion to iterate the whole data

Comment: thank you Anik Islam Abhi but pardon me as I am totally new to this ionic codes. I have been taking examples from Accordion List and modify it to change the value of the child..

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are referencing the whole object in `children`. Change `{{item.children}}` to `{{item.children.title}}`